# jQuery form submit

Tags: jquery

```
img="loader.gif (editeg link because i need 10 more reps to add img src tag)";

var pot=true;
function trimite(){
  if(pot==true){
   pot=false;
   jQuery("#loader").hide().html(img).slideDown();
   jQuery("#sec_code").fadeOut("slow");
   jQuery("#log_res").slideUp();
   jQuery.ajax({
    url:"register.php",
    type:"post",
    data:'utilizator='+jQuery("#utilizator").val()+'&parola='+jQuery("#parola").val()+'&reparola='+jQuery("#reparola").val()+'&mail='+jQuery("#mail").val()+'&security_code='+jQuery("#security_code_x").val(),
    success:function(msg){
     jQuery("#loader").hide().html(img).slideUp();
     jQuery("#log_res").hide().html(msg).slideDown();
     jQuery("#sec_code").html('<img style="margin-top: -2px;" src="captcha.php?'+Math.random()+'" />').fadeIn("slow");
     pot=true;
    }
   });
  } else return false;
 }
```

The form is:

edited image link, can't post img tag

when i click on submit, i get on the same page page.php?utilizator=somevalue&pass=somevalue etc, it doesn't makes the request on register.php .. why , i don't know, on js console, i get failed to load resource, but it exists .. it worked a while, but i don't know what i modified on it so it can't succesfully run.. 
Cheers, Edi.

Comment: If it fails to load the URL, it doesn't exist or a path is wrong. Use Firebug to debug the request - nothing much more we can do to help I think

Comment: Please show the code for the form or where you are calling trimite()

Comment: You show yourself defining the `trimite` function, but you don't show anything calling it. Is that your problem, or have you forgotten to include some necessary details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="javascript: return trimite();">
<input name="utilizator" type="text" class="password" id="utilizator" value="" size="32" maxlength="15">
<input name="parola" type="password" class="password" id="parola" value="" size="32" maxlength="30">
<input name="reparola" type="password" class="password" id="reparola" value="" size="32" maxlength="30">
<input name="mail" type="text" class="password" id="mail" value="" size="32" maxlength="40">
<img style="margin-top: -2px;" src="captcha.php" alt="ANTI SPAM !">
<input name="security_code" type="text" class="password" id="security_code_x" value="" size="5" maxlength="5">
<input type="submit" value="Inregistrare">
</form>
```

this is the form i submit with the jquery function trimite(); i load jquery v1.4.4 before the function.

Comment: the index.php the script.js and register.php are in the same folder

Comment: 1) You should edit your question with this information, not add it as an answer to your question. 2) You should not mix JavaScript into your HTML; instead: `<form id="foo">` and `$('#foo').submit(trimite);`

Comment: Phrogz, i did not quite understand what you ment with instead: <form id="foo"> and $('#foo').submit(trimite);

Comment: Again, a problem i met with, Array ( [username] => undefined [lume] => undefined [lang] => undefined ) I used POST and GET but jquery sends undefined variables to check.php ...

Comment: I still get undefined variables... just don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return false` in *either* case to prevent the default submit behavior...which is what's happening.  Make sure to `return false` from any code path in the function, otherwise it'll do a normal form submit (as if there's no JavaScript at all)...just like you're seeing.  Since there's no `action` attribute, it submits to the same page.

So this portion:

```
 });
} else return false;
```

Should be like this so it returns `false` regardless:

```
 });
}
return false;
```